# Is recomnder systems part of computer science?

Tags: recommendation-systems

I want to work on a paper with one of my friends in Recommender systems. My field is programming, and I favourite part is to be more technical.

I want to know that, is field of Recommender systems a part of Computer science or field in Information technology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithmic part of the  recommendation systems is more closely related to the computer science, the theoretical part of recommendation systems is mostly combination of statistics and linear algebra, thus we can think of recommendation systems as the combination of statistics and computer science, and the data science is the field that one would actually call the combination of statistics and computer science.

Thus my take on to answer the question is that the data science is the field you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you, so you mean that choose another part of data science? What is your offer with notice to my favourite fields?

Comment: I was suggesting that the in my vision recommendation systems of part of the data science as a field in information technology. Although, if you want to look at it from the perspective of computer science, recommendation systems are composed of many algorithms and as an example you can look into https://www.netflixprize.com/leaderboard.html, where many algorithms have been developed specifically for this competition.

Comment: That was awosome, I think I will get through it.